# Assigning to component of struct which taken as pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to take numbers from text file to put struct's component.

```
typedef struct{
 int x;
}A;
```

try 1: (fp is file pointer with read mode)

```
void foo(A *a){
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&(*a).x);
 }
```

try 2:

```
void foo(A *a){
  fscanf(fp,"%d",a->x);
 }
```

and a few more try similar to these. It is either segmentation fault or compile error. Seems like I'm having some trouble with signs `*`,`&`,`->`.

Comment: `&a->x` should work.. The first snippet should do as well. Segmentation fault is for some other reasons in the code you don't show

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct. It should work.

```
void foo(A *a){
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &(*a).x);
}
```

The following is not correct.

```
void foo(A *a){
  fscanf(fp, "%d", a->x);
}
```

`a->x` is the value of `a->x`, not the address of `a->x`, which is what you need.

You can change it to the following and it should work.

```
void foo(A *a){
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &(a->x));
}
```

Comment: The parentheses around `a->x` are unnecessary.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Agree. I prefer that style for my own sake. It is more readable to me.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's better than relying on one's understanding of operator precedence :)